# Giving folder permission as apache owner

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, web

I have set up the AWS Linux instance and deployed web project and for that project, I need folder permission only by apache user I have root user access for SSH.

How can I do this which will show apache as an owner of the web project?

Answer (score 1):

Apache creates **www-data** as the **user** and **group**.
Example: If the Server web root is /var/www.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Hope it helps ;-)